# Array of dictionary filter using predicate - swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, closures

I have array of dictionaries.

```
>[{"name": "John",
"address": 
{"home": "addr1", 
"work": "add2"}
},
{"name": "Anu",
"address": {"home": "addr1", 
"work": "add2"}
}]
```

I am saving it to user default like this -

let personsData1 = ["name": "John", "address": {"home": "addr1", "work": "add2"}] as [String : Any]
let personsData2 = ["name": "Anu", "address": {"home": "addr1", "work": "add2"}] as [String : Any]

```
var persons = [personsData, personsData1]
UserDefaults.standard.set(forKey: "persons")
```

Retrieving it in another method and filter them on the basis of name.
let name = "**John**"

Getting below error

**Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((Any?) -> Bool)'**

Here is the code :-

```
func test () {

    let personData1 = ["name": "John", "addresses": ["home":"addr1", "work": "addr2"]] as [String : Any]
    let personData2 = ["name": "And", "addresses":  ["home":"addr1", "work": "addr2"]] as [String : Any]

    let persons = [personData1, personData2]
    (UserDefaults.standard.set(persons, forKey: "persons")

    print("Saved ----\(UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "persons"))")

    if let savedPersons = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "persons") {
        let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name like %@", name);

        var filteredArray: [[String:Any]] = savedPersons.filter { namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0) }

        print("names = \(filteredArray)")
    }
}
```

If I try to filter like this -

```
let filteredArray = savedBrs.filter { $0["name"] == name }
```

getting different error -

**Value of type 'Any' has no member 'filter'**

Comment: Please include the code where you filter the array in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `NSPredicate`

```
let arr = [["name":"Rego","address":["one":"peek","two":"geelo"]],["name":"pppp","address":["one":"peek","two":"geelo"]]]

let neededName = "Rego"

let pre = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@",neededName)

let result = arr.filter { pre.evaluate(with:$0) } 

print(result)
```

Without `NSPredicate`

```
let result = arr.filter { $0["name"] as? String  == neededName }
```

Comment: I declared dictionary like this - let arr1: [[String:Any]] = [ ["name":"Rego","address":["one":"peek","two":"geelo"]],["name":"pppp","address":["one":"peek","two":"geelo"]]] Can't we use Any?

Comment: This declaration by default gives **[[String:Any]]**

Comment: If I save and then retrive this value from user defaults I am getting error ->value of type 'Any?' has no member 'filter'

Comment: My code for saving -> UserDefaults.standard.set(arr1, forKey: "persons")

let arr = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "persons")

Comment: when reading use **UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "persons")**

Comment: Got it. Thanks! I was retrieving it like normal value